# Read in string from user and convert to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, user-input

How can i store user input as a nsstring to be placed within an nsmutablearray? scanf is not working for string type.

```
-(NSString *) addMemo;
{
NSMutableArray  *memoArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSLog(@"Please add your memo.");
scanf("\n", &memo);
[memoArray addObject:memo];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `NSString`'s `stringWithCString:encoding:` constructor to create an `NSString` from `memo`.